# Foundation Text Grid

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to create a grid with text, not images, similar to the 'content section' in the Zurb template: http://foundation.zurb.com/templates/orbit.html

I would like to create three blocks of text on each row.

I am able to create this, but the problem that arises is that sometimes in my data there is only one or two blocks of text for a row.

For example, if a product is missing it's location, is there a way to move ingredients to take the place of location, or if category and location are missing to move ingredients to the place of category?

I'm using Ruby on Rails and Foundation 5.

Thanks!

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <% unless @product.category.nil? %>
      <div class="product-heading">Product Category</div>
      <div class="product-value">
        <%= @product.category %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <% unless @product.location.nil? %>
      <div class="product-heading">Product Location</div>
      <div class="product-value">
        <%= @product.location.sort.join(", ") %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <% unless @product.ingredients.nil? %>
      <div class="product-heading">Product Ingredients</div>
      <div class="product-value">
        <%= @product.ingredients.sort.join(", ") %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

HTML generated from Max Williams' suggestion.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <div class="product-heading">Product Category</div>
      <div class="product-value">Food </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <div class="product-heading">Product Ingredients</div>
      <div class="product-value">Flour, Sugar </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript to try and remove empty li tag

```
<script>$('li, p')
  .filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === '' && $(this).children().length == 0
  })
  .remove();
</script>
```

Comment: I think this will be easy to solve but you haven't given any details of your actual rails code, models, etc.  Eg, are you iterating over a collection of objects here?  You should include the relevant erb code as well as the rendered html.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I have updated the code. I'm a newbie, but I hope I've provided you with enough info. Thanks.

Comment: Can you use the `block-grid` instead? http://codeply.com/go/iouWc9rtUy

Comment: @Skelly Thanks for the code example. I've tried using the block-grid, but the blocks do not move when a block is missing. The HTML shows there is an empty <li></li> tag. If I delete this via the web inspector, then everything works. I've tried use javascript to remove the empty <li> tag but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to look for repeated elements, and abstract them out, for example by using a loop.  eg

```
<% product_cells = [["Category", @product.category], ["Location", @product.location_string], ["Ingredients", @product.ingredients_string]] %>
<div class="row">
  <% product_cells.each do |title, data| %>
    <% unless data.blank? %>    
      <div class="large-4 columns">
        <div class="product-heading">Product <%= title %></div>
        <div class="product-value"><%= data %> </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Note that i've put the test in a different place, so the whole large-4 div is skipped if the data is blank.

This sort of thing `@product.location.sort.join(", ")` should usually be replaced with a method in the Product model, eg

```
#in Product
def location_string
  self.location.reject(&:blank?).sort.join(", ")
end

def ingredients_string
  self.ingredients.reject(&:blank?).sort.join(", ")
end
```

then you could change the above code to

```
<% product_cells = [["Category", @product.category], ["Location", @product.location_string], ["Ingredients", @product.ingredients_string]] %>
```

EDIT: changed string methods to cope with nils

EDIT2: changed my original answer to use the model methods i added.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have now created methods in the Product model. I encounter two problems with your code. I get errors for join and sort: _undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass_. Also, the title and data do not move. I’ve updated my question to show you the html. Thanks.

Comment: The `undefined method `join/sort' for nil:NilClass` means that `self.location` or `self.ingredients` is returning some nil values.  I'll edit my methods.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the title and data do not move" please?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. Here’s an image of what I’m trying to achieve: http://imgur.com/6CKne8C. In the first scenario, the product has information for all three headings; in the second the product is missing information for product location, so I want to move product ingredients to take the place of product location and so on. I hope this makes sense. I’ve updated my string methods, but I now get the following error: `undefined method 'reject' for nil:NilClass`. I've managed to solve this by adding `unless self.category/location/ingredient.nil?` to each method. Thanks for your time + effort

Comment: Can you try with my latest edit?  I'd expect it to only render out two ".large-4" divs in the second row, where the location is blank.  Is that the case?

Comment: Correct. There are only two ".large-4" divs in the second row. It's just that they appear as in the image, with a large space in between them

Comment: My first instinct would be that there's some style rule eg :first-child, :last-child etc which is making them hug the left and right, but that wouldn't explain why row 2 and 3 are different when they both have two divs in them.  Can you add the rendered html, copied from the page source, for that table, in an edit to your question. (you can replace the section where you had the html for one row with the html for all rows and their containing element)

Comment: I've added the rendered html from the page source for the table.

Comment: No you haven't, you've added it for one row, which has three divs in it, i note.  Add the html for all four rows please, and their parent element.  You can delete any previous posted chunks of html, these will just confuse things.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I was just about to copy the rendered html and I figured out what was wrong. I needed to change `<div class="large-4 columns"> to <div class="large-4 columns end">`, ie add `end` and now it works perfectly. Greatly appreciate all of your help!